# Logcat is showing IndexOutOfBound exception after getting run of my android application

Tags: android, web-services, bar-chart

The logcat of my application is showing some IndexOutOfBound exception.Here i am trying to create a bar-chart in android using achartengine library.And i am getting the x-axis and y-axis values from the web service by consuming it,i am following SOAP method for consuming a web-service.Can any one let me know what mistake i am committing on my project?

Suggestions please!..

***Thanks for you precious time!..***

**LOGCAT**

```
10-25 11:44:32.713: W/KeyCharacterMap(928): No keyboard for id 0
10-25 11:44:32.723: W/KeyCharacterMap(928): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-25 11:44:40.383: D/AndroidRuntime(928): Shutting down VM
10-25 11:44:40.383: W/dalvikvm(928): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at com.example.barchart_test.Chart_MainActivity$1.onClick(Chart_MainActivity.java:43)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-25 11:44:40.393: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*Please find my sources for reference*

**Chart_MainActivity**

```
public class Chart_MainActivity extends Activity 
{
EditText edt1, edt2;
// TextView txt_1;
Button btn;
ArrayList<String> result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1_date1);
edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_date2);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_invoke);

result = new ArrayList<String>();

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        result.addAll(getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(), edt2.getText().toString()));

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("gotonextpageX", result.get(0));
        in.putExtra("gotonextpageY", result.get(1));

        startActivity(in);
    }
});}

private ArrayList<String> getTMSChart(String FromDate, String ToDate) 
{

// txt_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;

String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);
request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

String x = "", y = "";

ArrayList<String> stringResult = new ArrayList<String>();

try 
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) (result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
    int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++) 
    {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
        int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++) 
        {

            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No").toString());
            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate").toString());

        //  stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent").toString());

        //  freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{}

return stringResult;
}
}
```

**NextActivity**

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity 
{
double x,y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {   
        x = extras.getDouble("gotonextpageX");
        y = extras.getDouble("gotonextpageY");
    }
    else
    {}

    final GraphicalView gv =createIntent();
    RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlt);
    rl.addView(gv);
}   

public GraphicalView createIntent() 
{

    String[] titles = new String[] { "Orders profit"};

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { x });
    values.add(new double[] { y });


    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#77c4d3")};

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    setChartSettings(renderer,"","","",0.5,12.5, 0, y, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN);

    renderer.setXLabels(1);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);

    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "x");

    /*renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Feb");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Mar");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Apr");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "May");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Jun");*/


    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
      }

   final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(NextActivity.this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
   return grfv;
   }

   protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
   {

       XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

       renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
       renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);

       renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
       renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

       renderer.setBarSpacing(1);

       renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#0E120E"));
       renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
       renderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.WHITE);

       renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
       renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

       int length = colors.length;

       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
       {
           SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
           r.setColor(colors[i]);
           r.setChartValuesSpacing(-90);
           r.setChartValuesSpacing(15);
           renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
           }
          return renderer;
         }

   protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
   {
      XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
      int length = titles.length;

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
   {
       CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
       double[] v = values.get(i);
       int seriesLength = v.length;

       for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
       {
           series.add(v[k]);
           }
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        }

   return dataset;
  }

 protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
 String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
 {

     renderer.setChartTitle(title);
     renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);

     renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
     renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

     renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
     renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
     renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
     renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

     renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 10, 65, 10, 15 });

     renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
     renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
  }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.barchart_test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="15"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity   android:name=".Chart_MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_chart__main" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity   android:name=".NextActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_chart__main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show your Manifest.xml

Comment: Check this line `com.example.barchart_test.Chart_MainActivity$1.onClick(Chart_MainActivity.java:43)`

Comment: The `getTMSChart` method returns an empty list(probably an exception in that try-catch block) from which you then try to get elements.

Comment: @VenomVendor please visit my question again i have given my Manifest.xml for reference

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you getting something from server side? You don't checking result List size before getting elements from it.
As for me problem in this strings
in.putExtra("gotonextpageX", result.get(0));
in.putExtra("gotonextpageY", result.get(1));

Comment: I am sure i am getting the x-axis and y-axis values from the server successfully

Comment: Huh? Wherever you use x and y, you do not add them to the ArrayList. the returned list simply is empty. Also **you do a network call on the main thread**. You shouldn't do this - if it lasts too long your users will see an ANR error message!

Answer (score 0):

Add Array index out of bound Exception to your Main Activity  Code

```
try 
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) (result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
    int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++) 
    {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
        int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++) 
        {

            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No").toString());
            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate").toString());

        //  stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent").toString());

        //  freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));

        }
    }
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e) 
{}
catch (Exception e) 
{}
```

Comment: As for me, catching Runtime Exceptions - is bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
<activity   android:name=".NextActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chart__main" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

by

```
<activity android:name=".NextActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: This will not be the serious problem,i think so